# sending E-Mail via Microsoft Exchange

Tags: java, android, email, http, exchange-server

I am working on an App that should automatically log into Microsoft Exchange and should be able to send E-Mails. Is it possible to communicate with the Exchange Server through plain http or is an API for Exchange required? (SMTP is not an option.)

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2007 and above can be accessed via [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx). Specifically for Java there is an [API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api).

Comment: Thank you, but I know that. I can't use that API. Is it possible to do it without the API?

Comment: No is the short answer. EWS is the method to communicate to Exchange, there is no alternative.

Comment: My question wasn't formulated that good. Of course it is possible without a Java library (because that API is also just sending commands over tcp or even http). What I wanted to know is, is there a documented way to do, what the library would do?

Comment: I would say the second link in my answer would be the place to look first. EWS uses HTTPS (or http is you really have to) to communicate so in theory you could but it's not something I have tried personally.